# White OpenGL texture in some graphic cards

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am using following code to render a 1D texture. But in some graphic cards it renders only a solid white one. I noticed sometimes it is fixed after installing the card's driver.

```
          byte[,] Texture8 = new byte[,]
        {
            { 000, 000, 255 },   
            { 000, 255, 255 },   
            { 000, 255, 000 },   
            { 255, 255, 000 },   
            { 255, 000, 000 }   
        };

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture1D);

        // Set pixel storage mode 
        GL.PixelStore(PixelStoreParameter.UnpackAlignment, 1);

        // Generate a texture name
        texture = GL.GenTexture();

        // Create a texture object
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.ProxyTexture1D, texture);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture1D, 
                        TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, 
                        (int)All.Nearest);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture1D, 
                        TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, 
                        (int)All.Nearest);
        GL.TexImage1D(TextureTarget.Texture1D, 0, 
                      PixelInternalFormat.Three, /*with*/5, 0, 
                      PixelFormat.Rgb, 
                      PixelType.UnsignedByte, Texture8);
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Some drivers/cards (especially older ones) have issues with non-power of 2 sized textures.

Comment: How can I set a texture to be a power-of-two one?

Comment: By padding it out to the next power of two. In your case you'd add 3 extra pixels and change the width in `glTexImage1D` to 8.

Comment: @M.Elmi: You don't set a texture to be power of 2. You just supply it that way. You know, make either dimension so that it follows d = 2^n

Comment: OK. I tested it and it worked. Thank you so much. If one of you guys could post your reply to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some older graphics cards/drivers don't work properly with textures whose dimensions are not a power of 2.

In your case, you're creating a 1d texture of width 5, which isn't a power of two. So the solution is to pad your texture out to the nearest power of two (8) before calling `glTexImage1D`.

```
byte[,] Texture8 = new byte[,]
{
    { 000, 000, 255 },
    { 000, 255, 255 },
    { 000, 255, 000 },
    { 255, 255, 000 },
    { 255, 000, 000 },
    { 000, 000, 000 },
    { 000, 000, 000 },
    { 000, 000, 000 }
};

// ...

GL.TexImage1D(TextureTarget.Texture1D, 0, 
              PixelInternalFormat.Three, /*with*/8, 0, 
              PixelFormat.Rgb, 
              PixelType.UnsignedByte, Texture8);
```